# Join complementary tables in Postgesql

Tags: sql, postgresql, common-table-expression

Let's say I have two tables `table1`and `table2`, with three columns each, `id`, `time`, `value`. They store the same kind of information, ie. a 30-minutes timeseries data for several ids (let's imagine a machine that produces an amount of energy per day). `table2` contains more precise information than `table1`, but not for all timestamp nor all ids.

I want to get the best out of the two tables over the period defined by `table2`, ie. storing data from `table2` when available, and discarding to `table1` when required (to add some more complexity, let's say that `table1` is not a real table, but rather a view that takes a hell lot of time to be fully computed, so that I want to avoid compute it in its integrality).

I thought I could define a perimeter of id-time to indicate which value should be kept each day (teh daily scale should be equivalent to the 30-minutes timestamp, and be less resource-consuming). Thus I went for :

```sql
with perimeter_per_day_table2  as ( 
  select distinct 
         id, 
         date_trunc('day', time) as day
    from table2
), 

perimeter_per_day_table1 as (
  select id, 
         date_trunc('day', time) as day, 
    from table1
    where day >= (select min(time) from table2)
      and day <= (select max(time) from table2)
      and (id, day) not in (select id, day from perimeter_per_day_table2)
)

select * from perimeter_per_day_table1
```

but that takes a hell lot of time. In particular, it seems like the condition `where (id, day) not in (select id, day from perimeter_per_day_table2)` is very hard for Potsgresql to handle.

Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, `NOT IN` isn't optimized as well as `NOT EXIST` in Postgres. So an equivalent `not exists ()` condition is typically faster.

However, in neither case do you need to apply a (costly) DISTINCT on the rows in the sub-query.

```
with perimeter_per_day_table1 as (
  select t1.id, 
         date_trunc('day', t1.time) as day
  from table1 t1
  where t1.day >= (select min(time) from table2)
    and t1.day <= (select max(time) from table2)
    and not exists (select * 
                    from table2 t2 
                    where t1.id = t2.id
                      and t1.day = t2.day)
)
select * 
from perimeter_per_day_table1;
```

You can even avoid querying table2 twice for the min/max, but I doubt that will make a huge difference if there is an index on the `time` column:

```
with min_max as ( 
   select min(time) as min_time, 
          max(time) as max_time
   from table2
), perimeter_per_day_table1 as (
  select t1.id, 
         date_trunc('day', t1.time) as day
  from table1 t1
    cross join min_max 
  where t1.day >= min_max.min_time
    and t1.day <= min_max.max_time
    and not exists (select * 
                    from table2 t2 
                    where t1.id = t2.id
                      and t1.day = t2.day)
)
select * 
from perimeter_per_day_table1;
```

Comment: I didn't know 'not exists' is better than 'not in', thanks for the tip ! The difference is quite impressive.